# Dynamically add tab to navbarPage and select new tab

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to add a new tab to shiny's navbar page whenever another tab is clicked in the navbar.

The following works as expected, but I'd like to jump to the newly added tab (instead of jumping back to "Home").

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fillPage(
    uiOutput("updateableNavbar")
  )

)
```

server.R

```
function(input, output, session) {
  navbarParams <- reactiveValues(
    params = list(
      id = "navbar", 
      title = "navbar", 
      home = tabPanel("Home", titlePanel("Home")),
      add = navbarMenu("AddPanels",
                       tabPanel("AddPanel1", titlePanel("AddPanel1")), 
                       tabPanel("AddPanel2", titlePanel("AddPanel2"))
      )
    )
  )

  lastPanelKlicked <- NULL
  observe({    
    if(!is.null(input$navbar) && substr(input$navbar, 1, 8) == "AddPanel" && 
         (is.null(lastPanelKlicked) || lastPanelKlicked != input$navbar)) {   
      lastPanelKlicked <<- input$navbar
      print(input$navbar)
      params <- navbarParams$params
      params[[length(params) + 1]] <- tabPanel(input$navbar, titlePanel(input$navbar))
      names(params)[length(params)] <- input$navbar
      navbarParams$params <<- params
    }
  })  

  output$updateableNavbar <- renderUI({
    do.call(navbarPage, navbarParams$params)
  })  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that?

```
### server.R

function(input, output, session) {

  navbarParams <- reactiveValues(
    params = list(
      id = "navbar", 
      title = "navbar", 
      home = tabPanel("Home", titlePanel("Home")),
      add = navbarMenu("AddPanels",
                       tabPanel("AddPanel1", titlePanel("AddPanel1")), 
                       tabPanel("AddPanel2", titlePanel("AddPanel2"))
      )
    )
  )

  lastPanelKlicked <- NULL
  makeReactiveBinding("lastPanelKlicked")

  observe({    
    if(!is.null(input$navbar) && substr(input$navbar, 1, 8) == "AddPanel" && 
       (is.null(lastPanelKlicked) || paste0("Add", lastPanelKlicked) != input$navbar)) {

      # Above and below I changed the Value of lastPanelClicked

      lastPanelKlicked <<- substr(input$navbar, 4, 1000)
      print(lastPanelKlicked)
      params <- navbarParams$params
      params[[length(params) + 1]] <- tabPanel(lastPanelKlicked, titlePanel(lastPanelKlicked))
      names(params)[length(params)] <- lastPanelKlicked
      navbarParams$params <<- params
    }
  })  

  output$updateableNavbar <- renderUI({
    do.call(navbarPage, navbarParams$params)
  })  

  observe({
    updateNavbarPage(session, "navbar", lastPanelKlicked)
  })

}
```

I basically made `lastPanelKlicked` reactive such that after your parameters are set, the `observe`-statement with `updateNavbarPage` is triggered.

One problem though, is that you assigned `tabPanel`-IDs multiple times. All your panels (in your original code) are either called `AddPanel1` or `AddPanel2` and if you want to select a panel, it selects the first one with this name (which is the one in the `navbarMenu`). So I had to rename your generated panels with either `Panel1` or `Panel2` to illustrate how it works.

If you want to apply this solution, I recommend you to think of a pattern how to name your tabs such that you can call them unambiguously.

Please ask, if something is unclear!